# Where to find the results of Onishchik?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I would like to have a good reference where the results in

"Inclusion relations between transitive compact transformation groups"  https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=27:3740

can be found in English/French/Spanish.

I am particularly interested about decompositions of compact simple Lie groups. I have the translated version of the subsequent paper "Decompositions of Reductive Lie groups" where some results are mentioned, but still I am interested in the previous work.

Thanks.

Comment: The three answers were useful, but Martin's was the most accessible source for me, so it got marked as accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This paper was translated to English and appears in *[Fifteen papers on algebra](https://bookstore.ams.org/trans2-50/).* American Mathematical Society Translations. Series 2. Vol. 50; American Mathematical Society, Providence, R.I. 1966; [MR189949](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0189949).

This particular paper is on pages 5 to 58; [Zbl 0207.33604](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0207.33604) (and Zentralblatt entries for [other papers from this book](https://zbmath.org/?q=in:00223771)).

I did not find a copy that is freely available online, but you can see some parts in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=fkF6evEY6OAC&pg=PA5).

In case it is useful for somebody, here is also a link to the Russian original: http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/mmo134

Answer (score 7):

Onishchik has a book "Topology of transitive transformation groups", written in English, where this material is presented in Chapter 4. The book is excellent but hard to find. I recall being unable to find it in the US and reading it in the Oberwolfach library.

Comment: The best math library in the US is at the University of Michigan.  One should always check there if seeking hard-to-find math book in the US. I just checked, and sure enough they have it in stock (https://search.lib.umich.edu/catalog/record/002934754?query=topology%20of%20transitive%20transformation%20groups&utm_source=MLibrary), so perhaps it can be obtained from there by inter-library loan.

Answer (score 4):

if you have the Russian paper, which I do not, Google translate should do a satisfactory job; I tried it on a related paper by Onishchik, for which I do have the source: [Semi-simple decompositions of semi-simple Lie algebras](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=27828&option_lang=eng). A pass of the first paragraph through Google translate produces a result that seems quite workable:
<sub>I don't read Russian: no edits on my part, other than formatting.</sub>

[image]

Let $G$ be a Lie algebra, let $G'$ and $G''$ be its subalgebras, we say that the triple ($G, G', G''$) is a *decomposition* if $G = G' + G''$. A Lie group acting on a manifold $M$ is called *locally transitive* if at least one of its orbitals on $M$ is open. It is easy to see that studying decompositions of real Lie algebras is equivalent to studying the inclusion relations between locally transitive groups.
Lee transformations. If $G$ is a complex Lie algebra, $G'$ and $G''$ are its complex subalgebras, then the decomposition $(G, G', G'')$ is said to be *complex.* The decomposition is said to be *semisimple* if $G, G'$, and $G''$ are semisimple.The present paper is devoted to finding all the real and complex semisimple expansions.